# Could not convert string to float (Tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a Minecraft stronghold coordinates finder that uses float variables, here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import tan
from math import radians
def clicked():
    global x1, z1, f1, x2, z2, f2, x, z
    x1=float(x1_string)
    z1=float(z1_string)
    f1=float(f1_string)
    x2=float(x2_string)
    z2=float(z2_string)
    f2=float(f2_string)
    if f1 == 90.0 or f1 == -90.0:
        z = float(z1)
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f2))*z + x2 - tan(radians(-1*f2)*z2))
    elif f2 == 90.0 or f2 == -90.0:
        z = float(z2)
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f1))*z + x1 - tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)
    else:
        z = float((x2 - tan(radians(-1*f2))*z2 - x1 + tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)/(tan(radians(-1*f1)) - tan(radians(-1*f2))))
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f1))*z + x1 - tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)
    x = round(x)
    z = round(z)
    
    
window = Tk()
window.title("Minecraft Stronghold Finder")
window.geometry('1280x720')
text = Label(window, text="Welcome to the Minecraft Stronghold Finder", font = ('Arial Bold', 20))
text.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
text1 = Label(window, text="Input your coordinates and angles of view", font = ('Arial', 15))
text1.place(x = 0, y = 30)
text2 = Label(window, text="First throw:", font = ('Arial', 15))
text2.place(x = 0, y = 55)
text3 = Label(window, text="Second throw:", font = ('Arial', 15))
text3.place(x = 0, y = 105)
tx1 = Label(window, text="X:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tx1.place(x = 0, y = 80)
ex1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ex1.place(x = 25, y = 85)
tz1 = Label(window, text="Z:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tz1.place(x = 100, y = 80)
ez1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ez1.place(x = 125, y = 85)
tang1 = Label(window, text="Angle:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tang1.place(x = 200, y = 80)
eang1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
eang1.place(x = 260, y = 85)
tx2 = Label(window, text="X:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tx2.place(x = 0, y = 130)
ex2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ex2.place(x = 25, y = 135)
tz2 = Label(window, text="Z:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tz2.place(x = 100, y = 130)
ez2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ez2.place(x = 125, y = 135)
tang2 = Label(window, text="Angle:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tang2.place(x = 200, y = 130)
eang2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
eang2.place(x = 260, y = 135)
btn = Button(window, text="Calculate!", font = ('Arial Bold', 15), command = clicked)
btn.place(x = 350, y = 95)
x1_string=format(ex1.get)
z1_string=format(ez1.get)
f1_string=format(eang1.get)
x2_string=format(ex2.get)
z2_string=format(ez2.get)
f2_string=format(eang2.get)
    
textx = Label(window, text=x, font=('Arial Bold', 15))
textz = Label(window, text=z, font=('Arial Bold', 15))
textx.place(x = 155, y = 240)
textz.place(x = 165, y = 240)
text4 = Label(window, text='X:', font=('Arial Bold', 15))
text4.place(x = 140, y = 90)
text5 = Label(window, text='Z:', font=('Arial Bold', 15))
text5.place(x = 150, y = 90)
window.mainloop()
```

Python keeps giving me the following errors one of them is **impossibility of converting string to float**, the other is that **python doesn't see my x and z variables**, but I declared them global:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Minecraft Strongholf Finder.py", line 77, in <module>
    textx = Label(window, text=x, font=('Arial Bold', 15))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
Minecraft Strongholf Finder.py", line 9, in clicked
    x1=float(x1_string)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>>'
```

I'm new in programming, so please don't judge too harshly. Thank you all :)

Comment: It should be `x1_string=format(ex1.get())` and so on. Not sure if `format()` is of any use here.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘x1_string=format(ex1.get())’ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling the `.get()` method as soon as the widgets are initialized, they will permanently hold the an empty string and when casting to `float` it will throw an error.

I have made a few changes to your code, refer to it below

```
from tkinter import *
from math import tan
from math import radians
def clicked():
    global ex1, ez1, eang1, ex2, ez2, eang2, textx, textz
    x1=float(format(ex1.get()))
    z1=float(format(ez1.get()))
    f1=float(format(eang1.get()))
    x2=float(format(ex2.get()))
    z2=float(format(ez2.get()))
    f2=float(format(eang2.get()))
    if f1 == 90.0 or f1 == -90.0:
        z = float(z1)
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f2))*z + x2 - tan(radians(-1*f2)*z2))
    elif f2 == 90.0 or f2 == -90.0:
        z = float(z2)
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f1))*z + x1 - tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)
    else:
        z = float((x2 - tan(radians(-1*f2))*z2 - x1 + tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)/(tan(radians(-1*f1)) - tan(radians(-1*f2))))
        x = float(tan(radians(-1*f1))*z + x1 - tan(radians(-1*f1))*z1)
    x = round(x)
    z = round(z)
    textx.config(text=str(x))
    textz.config(text=str(z))
    
    
window = Tk()
window.title("Minecraft Stronghold Finder")
window.geometry('1280x720')
text = Label(window, text="Welcome to the Minecraft Stronghold Finder", font = ('Arial Bold', 20))
text.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
text1 = Label(window, text="Input your coordinates and angles of view", font = ('Arial', 15))
text1.place(x = 0, y = 30)
text2 = Label(window, text="First throw:", font = ('Arial', 15))
text2.place(x = 0, y = 55)
text3 = Label(window, text="Second throw:", font = ('Arial', 15))
text3.place(x = 0, y = 105)
tx1 = Label(window, text="X:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tx1.place(x = 0, y = 80)
ex1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ex1.place(x = 25, y = 85)
tz1 = Label(window, text="Z:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tz1.place(x = 100, y = 80)
ez1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ez1.place(x = 125, y = 85)
tang1 = Label(window, text="Angle:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tang1.place(x = 200, y = 80)
eang1 = Entry(window, width = 10)
eang1.place(x = 260, y = 85)
tx2 = Label(window, text="X:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tx2.place(x = 0, y = 130)
ex2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ex2.place(x = 25, y = 135)
tz2 = Label(window, text="Z:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tz2.place(x = 100, y = 130)
ez2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
ez2.place(x = 125, y = 135)
tang2 = Label(window, text="Angle:", font = ('Arial Bold', 15))
tang2.place(x = 200, y = 130)
eang2 = Entry(window, width = 10)
eang2.place(x = 260, y = 135)
btn = Button(window, text="Calculate!", font = ('Arial Bold', 15), command = clicked)
btn.place(x = 350, y = 95)
    
textx = Label(window, font=('Arial Bold', 15))
textz = Label(window, font=('Arial Bold', 15))
textx.place(x = 155, y = 240)
textz.place(x = 175, y = 240)
text4 = Label(window, text='X:', font=('Arial Bold', 15))
text4.place(x = 140, y = 90)
text5 = Label(window, text='Z:', font=('Arial Bold', 15))
text5.place(x = 150, y = 90)
window.mainloop()
```

**NOTES**

- Instead of making the retrieved values as global, I have made the `Text` instances global and then applied the `.get()` in the function `clicked()` followed by casing so that the current values in the entry are picked.
- There is no need to have the labels with variables `x` and `z` initially as changing the values of x and z will not affect the values of the label, you can make use of the `.config()` to change the values directly from the function.
- Make a condition to ensure that you only use non zero values of the angle, else you will end up dividing by 0 and this error will be thrown `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

Comment: Thank you for your help, the program is working now! Looks like there are a lot of I need to learn in tkinter.